# PHP Installation fails in sapi/cli/php

Tags: php

```
  ...
  ...
  "_xmlTextReaderNodeType", referenced from:
      _zm_startup_xmlreader in php_xmlreader.o
  "_xmlParseURIReference", referenced from:
      __dom_get_valid_file_path in document.o
      __xmlreader_get_valid_file_path in php_xmlreader.o
      _zif_xmlwriter_open_uri in php_xmlwriter.o
  "_valuePop", referenced from:
      _dom_xpath_ext_function_php in xpath.o
      _dom_xpath_ext_function_php in xpath.o
      _dom_xpath_ext_function_php in xpath.o
      _xsl_ext_function_php in xsltprocessor.o
      _xsl_ext_function_php in xsltprocessor.o
      _xsl_ext_function_php in xsltprocessor.o
  "_xmlTextReaderConstXmlLang", referenced from:
      _zm_startup_xmlreader in php_xmlreader.o
  "_xmlGetNodePath", referenced from:
      _zim_domnode_getNodePath in node.o
  "_xmlTextReaderReadInnerXml", referenced from:
      _zim_xmlreader_readInnerXml in php_xmlreader.o  "_xmlTextWriterEndElement", referenced from:
      _zif_xmlwriter_end_element in php_xmlwriter.o
      _zif_xmlwriter_write_element_ns in php_xmlwriter.o
      _zif_xmlwriter_write_element in php_xmlwriter.o
  "_xmlRelaxNGFreeValidCtxt", referenced from:
      __dom_document_relaxNG_validate in document.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Whenever running make, I'm receiving this error. Tried "brew install php", tried compiling and installing from source. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post about 10 lines above and below this error message, it would be helpful to get some context.

Comment: "_xmlTextReaderReadInnerXml", referenced from:
          _zim_xmlreader_readInnerXml in php_xmlreader.o  "_xmlTextWriterEndElement", referenced from:
          _zif_xmlwriter_end_element in php_xmlwriter.o
          _zif_xmlwriter_write_element_ns in php_xmlwriter.o
          _zif_xmlwriter_write_element in php_xmlwriter.o
      "_xmlRelaxNGFreeValidCtxt", referenced from:
          __dom_document_relaxNG_validate in document.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
    
Error seems to have changed...

Comment: If you could put that in the main post it would be great

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Had a similar issue, using `make clean` before `make` solved this error.

Comment: should be the accepted answer! Worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you used the [homebrew-php](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php) repo's PHP formula, it's a known issue. The configure seems to ignore the `libxml2` configure we pass to it (which uses the homebrew libxml2 formula) and persists in using the system `libxml2` instead.

Make sure to check the Issues in the repo above, and post them there as well so we can provide support.

For this issue, see: [homebrew-php#33](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues/33)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem make clean did the trick

Answer (score 0):

on AIX , `touch sapi/cli/php` and rerun **make**  command.